# Are the colors of visited links opposite of what they "should" be?

Tags: feature-request

Typically when I've visited a web page the visited color of the link is lighter than the unvisited link.

But that's not the case here.

Examples:

Non-visited

[image]

Visited

[image]

Visually there are reasons for using the darker colors are used for the unvisited links (i.e. draws your attention easier, easier visual filtering of items that are unread).

Not sure if this is on-topic for the Meta, but thought I would bring it up.

Comment: This might be for MSE more than here but what browser are you using would be a good start to see if we can reproduce the issue. We can always flagged this to me moved if need be. Should be able to look at the page source to see what is going on.

Comment: I'm using Chrome. I considered putting this on another Meta site, but the other sites I belong to (Stack Overflow, Super User) both use darker colors for non-visited links.

Comment: It might have to do with the Beta site theme which is why I suggested meta. You can still refer to this site.

Comment: @guitarthrower Really? On SO, the links are darker when I visit them, in fact, the colors are pretty much similar to what we have here...

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a similar issue on Chrome with opposite findings. I'm sure it is other browsers as well.

[image]

I have not read the question on the bottom. It is lighter but the difference is so subtle. I have the same finding with IE 8

[image]

Again, I have not read the question on the bottom. The difference is more noticeable here.

I'm going to look for a MetaSE post about this as you can't be the first to notice.

## Found One

One [MetaSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143809/beta-theme-visited-link-color-seems-wrong-to-me/143816#143816) post that discusses this.